# What is the difference between stationary point and critical point in Calculus?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What is the difference between stationary point and critical point? We find critical points by finding the roots of the derivative, but in which cases is a critical point not a stationary point? An example would be most helpful. I am asking this question because I ran into the following question:

> Locate the critical points and identify which critical points are stationary points.

So, obviously It's implying that not every critical point is a stationary point.

Comment: They are the same, it's just a matter of context and imagery which one gets used.  For example, if you're describing a trajectory, "stationary point" kind of makes more sense, but if you're graphing a function $y = f(x)$, then critical point makes more sense.  but the definition is the same.

Comment: According to some authors at least, a critical point is a point where either $f'(x) = 0$ or $f$ is not differentiable, whereas a stationary point is a point where $f$ is differentiable and $f'(x) = 0$.  See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CriticalPoint.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StationaryPoint.html for example.

Answer (score 8):

All stationary points are critical points but not all critical points are stationary points.

A more accurate definition of the two:

Critical Point:

Let $f$ be defined at $c$. Then, we have critical point wherever $f '(c)= 0$ or wherever $f(c)$ is not differentiable (or equivalently, $f '(c)$ is not defined). Endpoints of domain (if any) also come under critical points. (The endpoint should be included in the domain)

Points where  $f '(c)$ is not defined are called *singular points* and points where    $f '(c)$ is $0$ are called *stationary points*.

Stationary Point: As mentioned above.

Comment: To expand on this, a critical point is a place where there is potentially a maximum or a minimum. This can happen if the derivative is zero, or if the function is not differentiable at a point (there could be a vertex as in the absolute value function.) A stationary point is just where the derivative is zero. If you think of the derivative as a velocity, then those are places where the velocity is zero, and something with zero velocity is stationary.

Comment: Should it be "wherever $f(c)$ is not differentiable" instead of "wherever $f'(c)$ is not differentiable"?

Comment: @KennyLJ Yes, you're absolutely right. Oversight on my part.