# find the stationary points for $f(x)=x^{\frac 2 3}$.difference between the stationary point and critical point and one more called turning point.

Tags: functions, derivatives

> Find the stationary points for $f(x)=x^{\frac 2 3}$.

**My work**

I realized the following

$\spadesuit$ $f'(x)=\frac 2 3 x^{-\frac 1 3}$ which is not defined at $x=0$

$\spadesuit$ $f'(x)<0$ for $x<0$ and $f'(x)>0$ for $x>0$.

$\spadesuit$ So, $x=0$ must be a critical point which originally changes the sign of $f'$.

Can we conclude that $(0,f(0))$ is a stationary point here.

Clear me the doubt.

> I don't know the difference between the stationary point and critical
>   point and one more called turning point.

Clear me with the suitable examples.

Comment: As far as I know, a stationary point is the same as a critical point: where the derivative of a function is $0$.

Comment: you forgot the range of definition for the given function $f(x)=x^{2/3}$

Comment: I think there should be some difference ... because critical point is defined in this way, " the point which changes the sign of $f'$" So, $f'$ need not have the value $f"(x)=0$ at the point. It is clear that if $f"(x)=0$ then, that point is critical point as well as stationary point.@RaceBannon

Comment: $x\to x^2$ is defined for all $x\in \mathbb R$, So, this also have $\mathbb R$ as the domain know?@ Dr.sonnhard graubner

Comment: A point where the sign of $f'$ changes sign is usually called an *inflection point*, not a stationary point. The value of $f''$ there is either zero or undefined.

Comment: go to this link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368188/what-is-the-difference-between-stationary-point-and-critical-point-in-calculus?rq=1

Comment: No for e.g. has $(-10)^{2/3}$ complex values

Comment: why should be? $(-10)^{\frac 2 3}=((-10)^2)^\frac 1 3=100^{\frac 1 3}$ which is a real number know?? there may be complex numbers.. but i can choose the real entry...Am I right in my arguments???@Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: and when we write $((-10)^{1/3})^2$?

Comment: see also herehttp://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-10%29%5E%282%2F3%29

Comment: the range is given by $$x\geq 0$$

Comment: see also here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=range+of+x%5E%282%2F3%29

Comment: yes..but what is the problem on negatives...@Dr.SonnhardGraubner